# Separating a text variable into binary variables in R

Tags: r

I have patient-level data with a column called category_name_en, which contains patient characteristics. Although there are only 17 patient characteristics, there are currently more than 600 different unique categories in this column because most patients have more than one patient characteristic listed, separated by a "|". I would like to separate these categories into new columns and create binary variables (yes/no) to indicate if a patient has any of the categories. This will help avoid having a large number of combinations.

Here is a sample data frame (sample_df) to illustrate the problem:

```
    structure(list(category_name_en = c("Chronic Heart Disease | Genetic Blood Disorders (including Sickle Cell Anemia) | Diabetes",  
"Chronic Heart Disease | Diabetes | Pregnancy", "Chronic Heart Disease | Chronic Liver Disease | Diabetes",  
"Elderly ≥ 55 years old | Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease (including Asthma) | Acquired or Genetic Immunodeficiency  Disorders",  
"(Dialysis (Failure Kid | Diabetes | Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease (including Asthma)",  
"Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease (including Asthma) | Elderly ≥ 55 years old | Diabetes",  
"Genetic Blood Disorders (including Sickle Cell Anemia) | Chronic Heart Disease | Elderly ≥ 55 years old",  
"Chronic Heart Disease | Genetic Blood Disorders (including Sickle Cell Anemia) | Diabetes | Elderly ≥ 55 years old | Neurological Disease",  
"Elderly = 55 years old | Diabetes | Genetic Blood Disorders (including Sickle Cell Anemia)",  
"Pregnancy | Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease (including Asthma)",  
"Healthcare practitioners | Healthy Client | Diabetes", "Chronic Heart Disease | Elderly ≥ 55 years old |  (Dialysis (Failure Kid",  
"Healthy Client | Elderly = 55 years old | Pregnancy", "Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease (including Asthma) | Acquired or Genetic Immunodeficiency  Disorders",  
"Chronic Heart Disease | Elderly ≥ 55 years old | Diabetes",  
"Elderly ≥ 55 years old | Chronic Heart Disease | Diabetes | Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease (including Asthma)",  
"Elderly ≥ 55 years old | Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease (including Asthma) | Chronic Heart Disease | Chronic Liver Disease | Diabetes",  
"Chronic Heart Disease | Diabetes | Healthcare practitioners",  
"Cancer | Elderly ≥ 55 years old | Acquired or Genetic Immunodeficiency  Disorders",  
"Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease (including Asthma) | Cancer | Diabetes | Chronic Heart Disease"
), patid = c(428L, 625L, 149L, 356L, 393L, 444L, 618L, 622L,  
488L, 289L, 130L, 335L, 522L, 284L, 39L, 187L, 391L, 663L, 653L,  
563L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

I would like to transform this data frame into a format where each unique category becomes a separate column, and a binary variable indicates whether a patient has any of those categories. For example:

```
    | patid | Chronic Heart Disease | Genetic Blood Disorders | Diabetes | Pregnancy | Chronic Liver Disease | Elderly ≥ 55 years old | Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease | Acquired or Genetic Immunodeficiency Disorders | (Dialysis (Failure Kid | Neurological Disease | Healthcare practitioners | Healthy Client | Elderly = 55 years old | Cancer |
|-------|----------------------|-------------------------|----------|-----------|----------------------|-------------------------|---------------------------------------|-------------------------------------------------|-------------------------|---------------------------|----------------------|---------------------------|---------|
| 428 | Yes | Yes | Yes | No | No | No | No | No | No | No | No | No | No |
| 625 | Yes | No | Yes | Yes | No | No | No | No | No | No | No | No | No |
| 149 | Yes | No | Yes | No | Yes | No | No | No | No | No | No | No | No |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  separate_rows(category_name_en, sep = " \\| ") %>% 
  mutate(value = "Yes") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = category_name_en, 
              values_from = value,
              values_fill = "No")

# A tibble: 20 × 16
   patid `Chronic Heart Disease` Genetic Blood Disorders (including…¹ Diabetes Pregnancy
   <int> <chr>                   <chr>                                <chr>    <chr>    
 1   428 Yes                     Yes                                  Yes      No       
 2   625 Yes                     No                                   Yes      Yes      
 3   149 Yes                     No                                   Yes      No       
 4   356 No                      No                                   No       No       
 5   393 No                      No                                   Yes      No       
 6   444 No                      No                                   Yes      No       
 7   618 Yes                     Yes                                  No       No       
 8   622 Yes                     Yes                                  Yes      No       
 9   488 No                      Yes                                  Yes      No       
10   289 No                      No                                   No       Yes      
11   130 No                      No                                   Yes      No       
12   335 Yes                     No                                   No       No       
13   522 No                      No                                   No       Yes      
14   284 No                      No                                   No       No       
15    39 Yes                     No                                   Yes      No       
16   187 Yes                     No                                   Yes      No       
17   391 Yes                     No                                   Yes      No       
18   663 Yes                     No                                   Yes      No       
19   653 No                      No                                   No       No       
20   563 Yes                     No                                   Yes      No       
# ℹ abbreviated name: ¹​`Genetic Blood Disorders (including Sickle Cell Anemia)`
# ℹ 11 more variables: `Chronic Liver Disease` <chr>, `Elderly ≥ 55 years old` <chr>,
#   `Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease (including Asthma)` <chr>,
#   `Acquired or Genetic Immunodeficiency  Disorders` <chr>,
#   `(Dialysis (Failure Kid` <chr>, `Neurological Disease` <chr>,
#   `Elderly = 55 years old` <chr>, `Healthcare practitioners` <chr>,
#   `Healthy Client` <chr>, ` (Dialysis (Failure Kid` <chr>, Cancer <chr>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve desired result using tidyverse, so first lets load your input data

```
# Load tidyverse package
library(tidyverse)

# Original data
data <- structure(list(category_name_en = c("Chronic Heart Disease | Genetic Blood Disorders (including Sickle Cell Anemia) | Diabetes",  
                                    "Chronic Heart Disease | Diabetes | Pregnancy", "Chronic Heart Disease | Chronic Liver Disease | Diabetes",  
                                    "Elderly ≥ 55 years old | Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease (including Asthma) | Acquired or Genetic Immunodeficiency  Disorders",  
                                    "(Dialysis (Failure Kid | Diabetes | Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease (including Asthma)",  
                                    "Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease (including Asthma) | Elderly ≥ 55 years old | Diabetes",  
                                    "Genetic Blood Disorders (including Sickle Cell Anemia) | Chronic Heart Disease | Elderly ≥ 55 years old",  
                                    "Chronic Heart Disease | Genetic Blood Disorders (including Sickle Cell Anemia) | Diabetes | Elderly ≥ 55 years old | Neurological Disease",  
                                    "Elderly = 55 years old | Diabetes | Genetic Blood Disorders (including Sickle Cell Anemia)",  
                                    "Pregnancy | Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease (including Asthma)",  
                                    "Healthcare practitioners | Healthy Client | Diabetes", "Chronic Heart Disease | Elderly ≥ 55 years old |  (Dialysis (Failure Kid",  
                                    "Healthy Client | Elderly = 55 years old | Pregnancy", "Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease (including Asthma) | Acquired or Genetic Immunodeficiency  Disorders",  
                                    "Chronic Heart Disease | Elderly ≥ 55 years old | Diabetes",  
                                    "Elderly ≥ 55 years old | Chronic Heart Disease | Diabetes | Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease (including Asthma)",  
                                    "Elderly ≥ 55 years old | Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease (including Asthma) | Chronic Heart Disease | Chronic Liver Disease | Diabetes",  
                                    "Chronic Heart Disease | Diabetes | Healthcare practitioners",  
                                    "Cancer | Elderly ≥ 55 years old | Acquired or Genetic Immunodeficiency  Disorders",  
                                    "Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease (including Asthma) | Cancer | Diabetes | Chronic Heart Disease"
), patid = c(428L, 625L, 149L, 356L, 393L, 444L, 618L, 622L,  
             488L, 289L, 130L, 335L, 522L, 284L, 39L, 187L, 391L, 663L, 653L,  
             563L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))


# and now lets create function to split and preprocess data. 


# Function to transform categories to columns
transform_categories <- function(data) {
  data %>%
    mutate(category_name_en = str_replace_all(category_name_en, "\\(|\\)", "")) %>%
    separate_rows(category_name_en, sep = " \\| ") %>%
    mutate(value = "Yes") %>%
    spread(category_name_en, value, fill = "No")
}


# Apply the transformation
transformed_data <- transform_categories(data)
```

category_name_en = str_replace_all(category_name_en, "\(|\)", ""):
This part of the code modifies the category_name_en column. It uses str_replace_all from the stringr package to replace all occurrences of open and close parentheses "(" and ")" with an empty string, effectively removing them.

\( and \): These are regular expressions that represent the open and close parentheses. The double backslashes (\) are used to escape the special meaning of parentheses in regular expressions.

## ====================

The separate_rows function is used to separate a single character column containing delimited values into multiple rows while duplicating the rest of the data

and finally mutate(value = "Yes") %>%
spread(category_name_en, value, fill = "No") using to make wider and fill empty values with no/yes